# Why doesn't substiuting work here?

Tags: substitution

I know that:$$\int \cos x dx = \sin x +C$$
Substiute $x$ for $ax+b$:
$$\int \cos(ax+b) dx = \sin(ax+b) +C$$
but according to my book:
$$\int \cos(ax+b) dx = \frac{1}{a}\sin(ax+b) +C$$
Why doesn't substiuting work here?

Comment: If $y=ax+b$ then $dy=adx$.

Comment: Think about the chain rule. Since $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$, $\int f'(g(x))g'(x)dx=f(g(x))+C=\int f'(y)dy$ with the substitution $y=g(x)$.

Comment: @JohnDouma where can I learn more about what you just said?

Comment: @BadUsername You have to convert the differential when you apply substitution. This should be in the examples in your calculus book.

Comment: If your book has just gotten to $\int\cos xdx=\sin x+C$, then you'll want to look a chapter or so ahead for the section titled "$u$-substitution".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to substitute $x$ for $ax + b$ not only in argument of $\cos$, but also in differential: $\int \cos(ax + b)\, d\color{red}{(ax + b)} = \sin(ax + b)$.

This is equivalent to your citation, as $\int \cos(ax + b)\, d(ax + b) = a \cdot \int \cos(ax + b)\, dx$.